# How to read from Registry under LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: c#, registry, winreg

I am prepairing an Windows form application which will show the Bitness of currently installed office(2016). I have placed a Button(ChkBtn) and a Label(BitnessLbl) in my form, that will help to accomplish my task.
    The problem is that even though I can find the value of the 'Bitness'('x64' in my case) by searching in the registary, the program fails to locate the specified registary. I have added an image that will further explain my problem. And the code that I am using is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace GetOfficeBitness
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ChkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var arg = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook";
            var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(arg, false);//OpenSubKey(arg);
            /*var p = Registry.LocalMachine.GetSubKeyNames();
            var l = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common");
            var n = l.GetSubKeyNames();*/
            if (key != null)
            {
                if (key.GetValue("Bitness").ToString() == "x86" || key.GetValue("Bitness").ToString() == "X86")
                    BitnessLbl.Text = @"32 Bit Office";
                //Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                //Environment.Exit(0);
                BitnessLbl.Text = @"64 Bit Office";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Image link goes here:-
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUcuX.png

Comment: No image, some errors in code, please correct it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: hi pitersmx, I have rectified error. please Check now...

Comment: Hi Hans, my code is not throwing any exception, it only fails to find the 'Outlook' subkey..

Comment: When you try to read `"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0` - what happens then?

Comment: What "bitness" is your own application running under? You may be experiencing the [registry redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: It shows null(64 Bit Office is shown in the label),But I know it is not null! that is what you can see from the image, the path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook" is absolutely valid. But don't know what is going wrong!!???

Comment: Hi, pitersmx, when I read "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0" it works perfectly.. but as soon as I add the 'Outlook' part it fails...

Comment: Hi, Damien_The_Unbeliever, I am Actually debugging my application and the Build Platform Taeget is set to "Any CPU" and 'Prefer 32Bit' is Checked.

Comment: Hello,Damien_The_Unbeliever you are a genius, I just Changed the Platform target of my program to 'x64' which is same as my windows operating system bitness and Office bitness too. and it worked perfectly...Wow! but will you please tell me how to make my program platform(OS bitness) independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated in a comment, when your code is running as a 32-bit process, you're experiencing the effects of the [Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx).

When it looks like your code is accessing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software`, it is in fact accessing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node`.

To counter the effects, make sure you open your key using an appropriate method/overload that accepts a [`RegistryView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview(v=vs.110).aspx) and request the 64-bit view. E.g. you may need to use [`OpenBaseKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than using the built-in `LocalMachine` property as your starting point.

So, something along the lines of:

```
var key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine
                                 ,RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(arg, false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Damien_The_Unbeliever, but I am sorry to say, all that you suggested seems a bit confusing to me, I am not a pro in working with the registry too.So,  would you please take the trouble to put down a couple of line of sample code explaining what I should exactly do.

Comment: Thank you Damien_The_Unbeliever, for saving my day. :)